# Are view ids local to the activity context?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

What is the scope of the a view's identifier?

Is it local to its corresponding activity?

For example, if in **activity_main.xml** I specify

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message" />
```

Within my **DisplayMessageActivity.java** would I legally be able to access `R.id.edit_message`?

When I test this I get an exception, but none of the messages are clearly telling me it's due to accessing an "id out of context", or something along those lines. I'm getting errors like `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This question arose as I was following the beginner tutorial:

### https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

**EDIT**
Thanks both for clarifying the difference between the scope of `R.id` and that of the widget with id `R.id.edit_message` (in terms of accessing it by `fiewViewById()`).

I actually intended to ask "would I be able to call findViewById(R.id.edit_message) in Activity A to access a widget in Activity B". And from your answers it appears the answer to that question is "no".

In my code, I did not include a view with id `R.id.edit_message` in the ViewGroup of Activity B. That's probably why I got the errors.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace please? You seem to be having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @cricket_007 See my edit!

Comment: you can't access views that you don't have them locally. but you can access them by their reference from their own activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the scope of the a view's identifier?

The identifier is an integer. It does not have a scope.

> Within my DisplayMessageActivity.java would I legally be able to access R.id.edit_message?

If we assume that you mean "would I be able to call `findViewById(R.id.edit_message)` to access a widget?", you can certainly call it. Whether you get `null` or not will depend on whether the activity has a widget in its view hierarchy with that ID.

However, Activity A cannot call `findViewById()` to retrieve a widget from Activity B. The id is an integer and has no scope. However, *`findViewById()`* has a scope: the view hierarchy of whatever you call it on (e.g., an activity, a `ViewGroup`).

Answer (score 2):

Any id that you enter using the XML is processed and placed into a unique integer value in the `R.java` file (which you should not edit). ID values, in particular, go into `R.id`, just like the layout XML files you have would be identified by `R.layout`.

To answer your question, the scope is global. At least wherever you can

```
import your.package.name.R;
```

For example, you have two Activities that each have an `EditText` with `android:id="@+id/edit_message"`.
In that scenario, you can use `findViewById(R.id.edit_message)` in both Activities, but the value of `R.id.edit_message` is the same.

As far as "scoping" goes, `findViewById()` is the shorthand of `YourActivity.this.findViewById()`, so you would be searching the content view of the current Activity.

---

For the reason you get the exception. Hard to say. One possibility is that you used the wrong XML layout for `setContentView()` and `findViewById()` returned you null. You can read on the documentation for why that is.